# Зачем нам выдаётся PIN при запуске Flask сервера?

Tags: python, flask, веб-сервер

Зачем выдаёт PIN при запуске Flask сервера? Где он используется?

Comment: В отладчике, когда ваш код выбрасывает исключение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это секретный код для доступа к дебаггеру `Werkzeug` (находится в зависимостях `Flask`). Debugger PIN - это просто дополнительный уровень безопасности на случай, если вы случайно запустите приложение в режиме `DEBUG` на рабочем сервере. Сделано для того, чтобы злоумышленнику было сложнее получить доступ к чувствительной информации программы.

Разумеется, **никогда не используйте `DEBUG` на боевом сервере!**

Подробнее про debug mode в [документации](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#debug-mode).
Аналогичный вопрос на [английском](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54883379/17349246) StackOverflow.